# Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (not B+) USB polyfuse location

Tags: power, usb-power, fuses

Usual problem - USB power has gone.

Where is the fuse located on the board? The reduced schematics on the RPi webpage does not show the USB at all.

Comment: Why do you want to know?

Comment: I want replace it with something having a better rating

Comment: If you can't find the fuse (which is clearly visible and labelled in the bottom right hand corner near the power connector) it is doubtful you could replace it - even if you could find a replacement - which would be a poor idea anyway as it is doubtful if the board traces could carry more than 2.5A. NOTE the fuse is clearly labelled on the schematic.

Comment: I am not asking about the F1 fuse, Only the one protecting the USB!

Comment: There isn't one! USB Current is supplied through a Current-Limited Power Switch (AP2553?)

Comment: A legendary F3?

Comment: @Milliways definitely there is something between the USB power and the 5V on board which blows up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no information about it on the RPi website and something definitely has blown up on the board cutting the USB 5V supply, I have  decided to measure where the the "raw" USB input is and hardwire it on the board.

Here is my workaround (the wire should be shorter):

[image]
[image]

PP2/PP3 <-----> PP27

Comment: Don't you risk "starving" the RPi?

Comment: @GerardH.Pille I do, but the another choice is to bin the RPi. But the proper power + 330u cap will probably sort that problem out. Actually I have connected my USB device (it sources about 300mA) - the RPi is quite heavily loaded ~90-95% but the power looks OK (it is connected to the scope now)

Comment: You do have the problem even if the RPi is not "loaded" ?

Comment: The problem is that USB power is **dead**. And this test was only to check if I will not starve my RPi

Answer (score 0):

On this page there is a nice picture.

https://www.petervis.com/Raspberry_PI/Raspberry_Pi_Dead/Raspberry_Pi_Fuse.html

Comment: but it is not the RPI 3 only the older version. I have found a lots of old RPi information but nothing about the RPI 3 B (not B+)

Comment: Sorry.  Do you mean the 3B does not have the fuse as the 3B+ has?

Comment: And the yellow 3592 so close to the usb power port?  https://www.raspberrypi.org/app/uploads/2017/05/Raspberry-Pi-3-Back-1-1622x1080.jpg

Comment: I try t find that one which cuts the USB power.

Comment: That may not be a fuse at all.  Perhaps the Pi can manage how much power may go to the USB connectors.

Comment: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/raspberrypi/schematics/rpi_SCH_3b_1p2_reduced.pdf   but no pp27 on this diagram

Comment: @GerardH.Pille, please remove the space before the `https://...` so that it becomes a clickable link

Comment: So, there was seemingly too much space. I took it back and put it here: " ", in case someone could use it.

Answer (score 0):

An addition to the soldering solution:

It is PP1/PP2 <-----> PP27

PP3 is GND, so don't connect this with PP27.

See full list of test pads
https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=89522&p=628505&hilit=pp12%2Bpp13#p628505

Raspberry PI disables power on USB ports on reboot. With this modification there is always power on USB port and no "hardreset" of usb devices by just rebooting possible.