# No power to usb ports on raspberry pi 3B

Tags: usb, power, boot-issues, usb-power, hard-drive

I use external harddisk(connected via USB with its own power supply) to boot into dietpi on my raspberry pi. It works okay for a day(even with multiple reboots and poweroff). But the next day RPi sends no power to usb ports and so it doesn't boot.
 When I use SD card to boot it works. Ethernet port works and I'm able to SSH. I've plugged my external drive using the USB adapter to another computer and I can confirm that it is working. I am using the official power supply (2.5A 5.1V). 
If I try to boot after keeping the RPi off for more than 1 day from the external HDD it works again! But this repeats everytime.
I can't understand this peculiar behaviour of my rpi 3b.
I have also set **max_usb_current=1** in **boot/config.txt** but still no luck. 
***Here is the output of some of the commands I ran after booting with sd card on raspbian:***

**lsusb:**

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**lsblk:** *(with external HDD connected)*

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 29.8G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  256M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0 29.6G  0 part /
```

**dmesg | grep usb** *(A lot of over-current change errors messages)*

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ dmesg | grep usb
[ 1039.172044] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4012
[ 1039.430051] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4013
[ 1039.688057] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4014
[ 1039.946054] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4015
[ 1040.204102] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4016
[ 1040.461910] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4017
[ 1040.720016] usb 1-1-port2: over-current change #4018
```

**config.txt:**

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
#disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
#hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
#hdmi_group=1
#hdmi_mode=1

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d

program_usb_boot_mode=1

max_usb_current=1
```

Please help me resolve this issue. Thanks :)

Comment: perhaps you're blowing the polyfuse - perhaps the self powered HDD is sending bad voltage to your pi through USB? perhaps try a HUB between the pi and the HDD?

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, I've disconnected the HDD from raspberry pi and connected a USB Flash Drive, it doesn't detect that either. If I blew the polyfuse how is it working a few days later again? I can't understand that. Also if indeed the polyfuse is blown how do I check it and can I replace it?

Comment: the fuse resets itself after some time - of course, I may be totally wrong, perhaps there are no such things in the pi 3b ... but the fact that the USB has no power until you leave the pi off for a day suggests that is exactly what is happening

Comment: Is there a way to tell whether the fuse is blown or not? Perhaps either by looking at the board (I could add a photo over here for a better understanding) or in any other way?

Comment: So I came across this question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/89239/raspberry-pi-3-model-b-not-b-usb-polyfuse-location and I tried to measure if 5V is being supplied to the USB port or not (P1/P2 to P27) with a multimeter and turns out there is 5V going to USB. So what might be the issue? Are their any other checks I can do to find out what's wrong with my raspberry Pi? I've also tried connecting a USB flash drive and that too is not detected.

Comment: Okay so I measured voltage between PP3-PP27 as suggested here: https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=110164 and I found out for me it's fluctuating between 0.01V - 0.06V using the official power supply. I think that's too low? Maybe the power supply is faulty?